# Is it possible to combine portrait and landscape oriented subreports in a single report?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to combine portrait and landscape oriented subreports in a single report? I'm using iReport 3.7.6. I change the orientation of the one subreport but remains the orientation of the main report. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do it, but you can achieve a similar result using two 
separate reports, one vertical and another one landscaped, fill the reports 
(using JasperFillManager.fillReport method) and put the resulting filled 
reports together in a final file (using JRPdfExporter). You can see this 
aproach in the [JasperReports forum](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=16091).

It works for me with iReport 4.0.1.

I hope that late answer could help you or other people.